# DENSE_RANK() when ORDER BY column values are the same

Tags: sql, ssms, dense-rank

I'm trying to rank a list of payments using DENSE_RANK() function and ordering the results by two data points [PAYROLL DATE] and [PROCESS DATE]. If the [PAYROLL DATE] is null, then the [PROCESS DATE] should be used. If there is more than one row with the same [PAYROLL DATE] they are ranked the same. However, if a [PROCESS DATE] row has the same value as [PAYROLL DATE] they are ranked separately.

I got some help earlier on stackoverflow, but as I was playing around with the data, I am not getting the desired results unless the duplicate [PROCESS DATE] is at the "end" of the data set.

Here is a snippet of what my query says.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Plan_ID],ee_id,loan_number ORDER BY CASE WHEN payroll_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, payroll_date, process_date ASC)
```

| [Plan ID] | [EE ID] | [Loan Num] | [PAYROLL DATE] | [PROCESS DATE] | (Desired) RANK | (Actual) RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 11/26/2021 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | NULL | 11/26/2021 | 2 | 3 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 02/18/2022 | NULL | 3 | 2 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 02/18/2022 | NULL | 3 | 2 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | NULL | 02/18/2022 | 4 | 4 |

In the above example, I want the ranking to use the payroll_date and process_date. What I am seeing is the payroll_date values are being ranked first and then process_date. But I want both payroll_date and process_date to be ordered by date, not ranking all the payroll_date values first and then process_date.

```
create table table1 (
  plan_id varchar(10), 
  ee_id integer, 
  loan_number integer, 
  payroll_date date, 
  process_date date);

insert into table1 values 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2021-11-26', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, null, '2021-11-26'), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2022-02-18', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2022-02-18', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, null, '2022-02-18'); 

SELECT 
*
,PayNum = 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Plan_ID],ee_id,loan_number ORDER BY CASE WHEN payroll_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, payroll_date, process_date ASC)
FROM table1
ORDER BY ISNULL(payroll_date,process_date)
```

I've tried different variations of DENSE_RANK() with different ORDER BY statements, CASE statements to no avail. I've also tried RANK() and ROW_NUMBER() and nothing is truly giving me what I'm looking for in the results.

Comment: What does this mean?  `I want both payroll_date and process_date to be ordered by date, not ranking all the payroll_date values first and then process_date.` Order By only works one way.

Comment: Another way to say is that I don't want all the rows with a payroll_date to be ranked and THEN all the rows with a process_date to ranked. In my example, I want 11/26/2021 to be "first" and the payroll_date is 1 and the process_date is 2. Then, the 2/18/2022 is the next date to rank. I want the 2 rows with the payroll_date value of 2/18 to be 3 and last the row with the process_date of 2/18 to be 4. I know it's kinda confusing. Sorry if I'm not explaining it very well. My "desired" column is a better visual of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order by in the partitiion and "join" the columns

```
SELECT 
*
,PayNum = 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Plan_ID],ee_id,loan_number 
  ORDER BY  COALESCE(payroll_date, process_date) , CASE WHEN payroll_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1
ORDER BY ISNULL(payroll_date,process_date)
```

| plan_id | ee_id | loan_number | payroll_date | process_date | PayNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2021-11-26 | *null* | 1 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | *null* | 2021-11-26 | 2 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2022-02-18 | *null* | 3 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2022-02-18 | *null* | 3 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | *null* | 2022-02-18 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MjWemyPl)

Comment: Oh, thank you so so much! I'm learning so much in the community. Thank you for not making me feel dumb. :-)

Comment: that has nothing to do with dumb, window function are complicated to understand and need much experience, asking question help to grasp the concepts